# Eigenvalue derivative

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this eigenvalue problem $[\varepsilon -\varepsilon_iI]n_i=0$, and I want to find  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon}n_i\otimes n_i $$, where $n_i$ is eigenvector and $\varepsilon$ is symmetric matrix 3x3. I know that i will have three case depends on relation beween $\varepsilon_i$, first case is when we have distinct $\varepsilon_i$ or $\varepsilon_1 \neq \varepsilon_2 \neq \varepsilon_3$, second when we have two the same principal values  $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon_2 \neq \varepsilon_3$, and third one is when $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon_3$.

Is there any book or paper which shows how this can be done in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first chapter of Kato's perturbation theory of linear operators will tell you more than you ever wanted to know.